# Dimension Mismatch in VGG Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I want to create VGG model with Keras.
However, following error was displayed:

> expected lstm_input_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (60000, 10)

I created the following sequential model:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     padding='same',
                     input_shape=input_shape)) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Please tell me why this error created.

Comment: `lstm_input` isn´t very probable part of your VGG model. Can you give more complete code and the full error log? Since the error refers to your input shape: How do you feed in your data?

Comment: And just for completeness sake: The easiest way to start with VGG would be to import it from Keras Applications: https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a Flatten layer like so:

```
…
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten()) # <-- this layer is missing in your code

model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
…
```

This transforms your last 2d layer (MaxPooling2D) to a 1-dimensional shape that you than can feed into your Dense layer.